# C# 'object' Extend method just for WPF ListBox Control

Tags: c#, wpf, methods, controls, extend

I had create a extend method for WPF ListBox control for treat **ListBox SelectedItem**, but I want turn this better, I want show my extend method when I type `listBox1.SelectedItem.MyExtendMethod();`

I can change my method for `public static void MyExtendMethod(this object item)`, but it will show for all 'object'

What can I do for this extend method just show for ListBox>objects? this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, no. Since extension methods know nothing about the call site, you can't restrict one to `ListBox.SelectedItem`. You're probably better off just applying it to `ListBox`.

Answer (score 0):

Data type for ListBox.Selecteditem is object. So your extension method need use 'object' data type for 'this'.

It is however possible by working on SelectedItem inside an extension method that is explicitly defined for ListBox.

E.g.

```
public static class ListBoxExtensionMethod
{
    public static void yourSpecialExtendedMethodForSelectedItem(this ListBox listBox)
    {
        // do your work here on listBox.SelectedItem
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of 'this ListBox' shouldn't it be 'this Selector'?  So as to maximize the method's utility?